# How to change content flow?

Tags: css, html, css-position

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCLPC/3/), I'm trying to create a bookmark shape.  There is only one triangle which needs to change its positioning.

```
<div id = "bookmark">
  <div id = "rectangle"></div>
  <div id = "triangle-topleft"></div>
  <div id = "triangle-topright"></div>
</div>
```

I could easily use relative positioning and shift it, but I don't want to do it this way.  I want a more malleable solution.

Instead of the shapes flowing from top to bottom.  I want the last shape to flow left to right.  So there are 3 shapes, the first two are in the perfect place, but the third one needs to be placed to the right of the second shape, instead of underneath it.

What CSS can I use to do this?

Comment: I am explicitly setting the default position as a matter of preference.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nfxYE/3/ - this wast he simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `float: left` to `#triangle-topleft` and `margin-left: 100px` to `#triangle-topright`.

To remove unnecessary markup, you could also use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements instead of `#triangle-*`.

Comment: not sure, who answered first, you or fred, but this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5):

Add `float:left;` to `#triangle-topleft` and `margin-left:100px;` to `#triangle-topright`

```
#triangle-topleft {
    position: static;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid black;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    float:left;
}
#triangle-topright {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid black;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TCLPC/4/)**

Answer (score 4):

First of all you do not have to declare `position: static;` as it is already static by default (Unless you are using `responsive design` where you need to reset the property value at certain point of resolution), secondly, assign `position: relative;` to your `#bookmark` and make the second triangle `position: absolute;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TCLPC/5/)

```
#bookmark{
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#rectangle {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 300px; 
    background: black; 
}
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 100px solid black; 
    border-right: 100px solid transparent; 
}

#triangle-topright {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 100px solid black; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

Note: Make sure you do not make your first triangle `position: absolute;` else you need to reposition the triangles. But this is the best method you can get, as you've wrapped `absolute` inside a `relative` container.

---

You can also take a look at this awesome thing - [Font Awesome - Bookmark](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/bookmark/), you can resize this to whatever size you want to.

---

The thing you are trying can be also achieved by using `:before` and `:after` pseudo along with `content` property. So you can get rid of the extra triangle elements.

---

As I said, you can create this thing with a single element.

```
#bookmark{
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px; 
  background: black; 
}

#bookmark:before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid black; 
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
}

#bookmark:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid black; 
  border-left: 100px solid transparent; 
  bottom: -100px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
```

Here, am using `:before` and `:after` pseudo, with `display: block;` and `content: "";` which are essential to get this thing work, also am positioning both the elements using `absolute` with a value set to `-100`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TCLPC/9/) (Using single element)

> Note: `:before` and `:after` pseudo can fail in older versions of IE,
>   but you can always use polyfills to use `CSS 3` properties, also, for
>   more information on browser support, you can check [this](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) out.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting obviously, as I've positioned the element using those properties, I've also edited my answer, you can see the very last demo shared by me, I just added that.

Answer (score 1):

Add display:inline-block to both triangle shapes.  They're stacking because they are defaulting to display:block.

Comment: In which case you will want to remove whitespace between the two triangles

Comment: Was going for more 'here's how to arrange those horizontally' rather than 'here, copy and paste this'. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to just add `float:left` to #triangle-topleft and #triangle-topright.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfxYE/

Comment: not sure, who answered first, you or instanceofme, but this is the simplest solution.